# Issue in Firefox browser with Worpdress WP Bakery vc_carousel

Tags: wordpress, firefox, wpbakery

I need help to figure how to solve this issue that occur in firefox browser only in my WP 6.2.2 website that use image carousel with WP Bakery plugin.
The error is:
**"Uncaught TypeError: $.support.transition is undefined"**
the file where the error occurs is **"lib/vc_carousel/js/vc_carousel.min.js"**.

In firefix with this error carousels are not displayed correctly and/or images not loading, in all other browsers I am unable to reproduce the issue, all work fine.

I tried many WP/plugin versions with no luck.
Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

I tried many WP versions, WP Bakery plugin versions and to edit js file with no luck.

Comment: I came across this post because I have the same problem on another website, but in my case the images are showing and everything seems to work but got the same message in the developer console.
Therefore it seems that it is a general problem.
If you purchased this plugin separately, you can and should let WPBakery know about it so they can investigate this further and hopefully fix it ASAP.
Maybe there is some conflict with other scripts e.g. bootstrap.